# Gas expansion by turbine and by orifice

Tags: thermodynamics, gas

What is the difference between gas expansion by turbine, and gas expansion by orifice. Because in turbine we get useful work, while in orifice we don't.
Please show PV (and or TS) diagram path for gas expasion by turbine, and gas expansion by orifice?

Comment: Which are you considering? a Gas Turbine or a Refrigerant cooling system?

Comment: Refrigerant cooling system

Comment: Then you need to re-write your question clearly.

Comment: You might find checking the Brayton cycle will help you.

Answer (score 2):

from wikipedia: [Joule-Thomson Expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule%E2%80%93Thomson_effect)

> The adiabatic (no heat exchanged) expansion of a gas may be carried out in a number of ways. The change in temperature experienced by the gas during expansion depends not only on the initial and final pressure, but also on the manner in which the expansion is carried out.
>
> If the expansion process is reversible, meaning that the gas is in
> thermodynamic equilibrium at all times, it is called an isentropic
> expansion. In this scenario, the gas does positive work during the
> expansion, and its temperature decreases.  {This is the case of a turbine expander}
>
> In a free expansion, on the other hand, the gas does no work and
> absorbs no heat, so the internal energy is conserved. Expanded in this
> manner, the temperature of an ideal gas would remain constant, but the
> temperature of a real gas decreases, except at very high temperature.
> [9]
>
> The method of expansion discussed in this article, in which a gas or
> liquid at pressure P1 flows into a region of lower pressure P2 without
> significant change in kinetic energy, is called the Joule–Thomson
> expansion. The expansion is inherently irreversible. During this
> expansion, enthalpy remains unchanged (see proof below). Unlike a free
> expansion, work is done, causing a change in internal energy. Whether
> the internal energy increases or decreases is determined by whether
> work is done on or by the fluid; that is determined by the initial and
> final states of the expansion and the properties of the fluid.

Answer (score 1):

(This is a non-expert non-formal answer but there aren't any other answers at the moment and perhaps it will help connect some concepts. Corrections to terminology and details welcome.)

In *either* situation, the expansion of the gas converts potential energy (which came from whatever pressurized the gas) into kinetic energy (in the form of the outward flow of the expanding gas). Putting a turbine in the path of the expanding gas converts that kinetic energy into rotation of the turbine and shaft due to the gas molecules striking the turbine blades.

Now, suppose there is not a turbine. Ignore the orifice for a moment — just assume we have some source of high-pressure gas, and imagine what happens as it is allowed to expand into a lower-pressure environment. What happens to the potential energy? If it is vented to atmosphere then it turns into wind and sound — that energy is wasted. This is not conceptually different from a fan blowing nowhere in particular — it is causing gas to move, and that flow is not captured by any further step, and so the energy input to the fan eventually becomes heat in the atmosphere. If instead the gas started out pressurized, then the energy that was used to pressurize the gas (perhaps some time ago) substitutes for the energy input to the fan.

If you insert an orifice in the path then you are **restricting the flow rate** of the gas, and causing the expansion to occur at a particular region of space (immediately after the orifice). This does not by itself change the long-term outcome, but it changes the rate and location at which the process occurs.

If you let the outflow from the orifice vent to atmosphere, then you have nothing more useful than a leak in your high-pressure system. But you could instead do something else with it. For example, if you pass the expanded (and therefore lower-temperature) gas through the piping of a heat exchanger, then you have (part of) a refrigeration system.

The orifice does not produce useful work because it changes the characteristics of the gas flow without *extracting* useful work from it. In order to understand whether it has useful effect, and where the energy ends up, **you need to look at what is downstream of the orifice.**

Comment: So the path on diagram Pressure vs. Enthalpy is the same for both process? Let's assume this is refrigerant in cooling system.

Comment: @RainerJ I am not knowledgeable enough in the actual mathematics of thermodynamics to answer that question; sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The diagram will look depending on the working fluid and its conditions, In the case of air if you have a look at this link at the Nasa.gov [website](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/BGP/brayton.html), I think it might answer your question. The turbine and nozzle (orifice) are shown to have the same characteristic however in reality they might have different isentropic efficiencies.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).